# Angular Animation - Improve reflow with animations

Tags: angularjs, css-animations

I'm using [ngFx](https://github.com/AngularClass/ng-fx) for my animations in an angular app (and new to the world of angular)

ngFX is great - seems very easy to use, but I want to improve how it deals with resizing the containing element.

Easy to see below, upon removal of the image the containing div instantly resizes - I want that to be smooth, i.e. it takes 1 sec to resize instead of that instant jump.

Not sure where to start fixing this issue.

Thanks

[image]

```
<div class="well well-lg">
    <h1 style="margin-bottom: 20px">NG SHOW</h1>
    <button style="margin-bottom: 20px" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="showdog = !showdog">TOGGLE</button>
    <br>

    <img class="fx-fade-up-big" ng-show="showdog" src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/7/77/200px-SantasLittleHelper.png/revision/20090712224020" >
</div>
```

Comment: have you checked this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143702/how-to-animate-a-div-height-change-with-angularjs

Comment: @Gonzalo.- yeah tried that - cannot get it to work with ngFx.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle so we can play with it ?

Comment: Its all good - I don't think it possible.